# discord.py bot and webhooks box messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, discord, discord.py

How can I make my Discord bot or webhook send a message like that by python ?

Like that :

[image: Screenshot]

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/343944376055103488/714172172180127825/test-by-deku_-_Discord_5_24_2020_8_43_17_PM_LI.jpg

```
I cannot make it as a image post because I don't have 10 reputations :(
```

Comment: Please check the [embed](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#embed) docs.

Answer (score -1):

Well I would use the dhooks library, it is a really easy library

I have a github repo that uses that with a bot

- Dhooks = https://pypi.org/project/dhooks/
- Repo = https://github.com/x-name15/Proxies-Discord-Bot